# Calling factories within another factory

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I am currently learning how to write PHPUnit test using a laravel app and hit a brick wall for some days now. My test was to allow only authenticated users update a book record if the user's id is the same as the book's user's id.

```
public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanUpdateBookSuccessfully()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    Passport::actingAs($user);

    $book = factory(Book::class)->create();

    dd($user, $book);

    // $response = $this->json('PUT', '/api/books/'.$book->id, [
    //         'id'    => $book->id,
    //         'title' => 'Updated book title',
    //         'author'=> 'New Guy'
    //     ]);

    // $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

But I got a 403 error initially and while troubleshooting, i noticed from the dumped data that the created user's id is not the same as the book's user_id.

```
// Newly created user
#original: array:7 [
    "name" => "Prof. Norwood Erdman"
    "email" => "ihoeger@example.com"
    "updated_at" => "2018-10-03 14:11:20"
    "created_at" => "2018-10-03 14:11:20"
    "id" => 2
]

// Newly created book
#attributes: array:6 [
    "title" => "Quasi laudantium enim quas omnis."
    "author" => "Mr. Jayson Roob"
    "user_id" => 1
    "updated_at" => "2018-10-03 14:11:20"
    "created_at" => "2018-10-03 14:11:20"
    "id" => 3
]
```

Going through my code, I discovered that every time a book is created the user_id will be set to 1 because my BooksFactory is using a hard coded value of `user_id = 1`.

```
$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'title'     => $faker->sentence,
    'author'    => $faker->name,
    'user_id'   => 1
];
});
```

How can I write my code so that in my test when a book is created, the authenticated user's id is assigned as the book's user's id? I think that will fix the test. I am using sqlite memory database for test and not mysql.

Answer (score 8):

You can override attributes in a factory by passing an array to the `create()` method with the attributes and values that you want to override:

```
$book = factory(Book::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

---

Furthermore, it might be a good idea to create create the user in the factory itself i.e.:

```
$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'     => $faker->sentence,
        'author'    => $faker->name,
        'user_id'   => function () {
            return factory(App\User::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

The reason the `user_id` value in wrapped in a closure is to stop another user being created if you want to pass in your own id.

[Overriding Attributes Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#overriding-attributes)

Comment: I want to create the user in the book factory itself, so I prefer to go with that solution. However that leaves me with another issue, how will i write the test case? using `$response = $this->actingAs($user)->json...` will definitely throw undefined user error. So how do I call up an update test?

Answer (score 1):

As a small update, for Laravel 8, the syntax would be:

```
$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'     => $faker->sentence,
        'author'    => $faker->name,
        'user_id'   => User::factory()->create()->id
    ];
});
```

Comment: thank you. this worked in laravel8.  what about polymorphic factory to create commentable_id and return also commendable_type?